# cannot be indexed twice on excluded files

Tags: sonarqube

I am using eclipse plugin sonarlint and have this in eclipse settings:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.js, node_modules/*, _ref/**

sonar.test.exclusions=**/*.js, node_modules/*, _ref/**
```

the "_ref" is a linked eclipse folder from within the same project folder, so sonar indexes the content of "_ref" which is equal to the content of "src/main/web/js". However, I excluded the linked folder. Does not help.

I get this error:

> Error during execution of SonarLint analysis File
>   [path=home/test/src/main.js] can't be indexed twice.

I have excluded js files from sonar, so why it is indexed?